# Find files not in numerical list

Tags: linux, bash

I have a giant list of files that are all currently numbered in sequential order with different file extensions.

```
3400.PDF
3401.xls
3402.doc
```

There are roughly 1400 of these files in a directory. What I would like to know is how to find numbers that do not exist in the sequence.

I've tried to write a bash script for this but my bash-fu is weak.

I can get a list of the files without their extensions by using

`FILES=$(ls -1 | sed -e 's/\..*$//')`

<s>but a few places I've seen say to not use `ls` in this manner.</s>
(15 days after asking, I couldn't relocate where I read this, if it existed at all...)

I can also get the first file via `ls | head -n 1` but Im pretty sure I'm making this a whole lot more complicated that I need to.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what reason do those few places you've seen give for their claim?

Comment: You know, I went back and looked for examples to share, but I couldn't find any. I very well may have pulled that information out of thin air :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want to do something like this:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for i in {1..1400}; do 
    files=($i.*)
    (( ${#files[@]} > 0 )) || echo "no files beginning with $i"; 
done
```

This uses a glob to make an array of all files `1.*`, `2.*` etc. It then compares the length of the array to 0. If there are no files matching the pattern, the message is printed.

Enabling `nullglob` is important as otherwise, when there are no files matching the array will contain one element: the literal value `'1.*'`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on deleted answer that was largely correct:

```
for i in $(seq 1 1400); do ls $i.* > /dev/null 2>&1 || echo $i; done
```

Comment: Ahem. Fixed. Thanks :)

Comment: `test` (or equivalently, `[`) does the job but fails with "too many arguments" if there are more than one file starting with the number.

Comment: Good point. Updated to a version that does work for that case, though it's still less elegant than yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls [0-9]* \
| awk -F. '  !seen[$1]++ { ++N }
             END         { for (n=1; N ; ++n) if (!seen[n]) print n; else --N }
'
```

Will stop when it's filled the last gap, sub in `N>0 || n < 3000` to go at least that far.